# what is the difference between PGA and LGA

Tags: cpu, motherboard

I'm learning `compTIA` a+ but i don't know what is the difference between `PGA` and `LGA` and i don't want to step into sockets before knowing what is the difference thanks in advance

Comment: This is easily searched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PGA or Pin Grid array are having the pins on the CPU itself like this.

[image: PGA picture]

LGA or Land Grid array are having the pins on the motherboard itself like this.
[image: LGA picture]

Comment: If you could include some pictures or something just to make your answer more detailed in appearance. You could also mention the pin and grooves for each the CPU and board. Another good point would be that PGA is AMD and LGA is Intel. This input is only given because for some reason someone gave you a downvote, even though your answer is correct.

Comment: @DrZoo not all LGA are intel and not all PGA are AMD just like `AMD socket f` it is LGA and AMD

Comment: thank though i have added some images